# Detect all changes to a nested table in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

Assume I have a nested table like this:

```lua
local a = {
  b = {
    c = {
      d = 'e'
    }
  },
  f = {
    g = {
      h = {
        i = 'j'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(Ignore the variable names, they're just placeholders)

So what I want to know is, how do I trigger a function everytime that table or any of its sub-tables are modified. For example, if I do `a = { 'something' }` or if I do `a.b = { 'something' }` or if I do `a.b.c = { 'something' }` and so on. Using the `__newindex` metamethod in a metatable that uses a proxy table I can only trigger the function on the second case. (eg: when I do `a.b = { 'something' }`)

Is there a way to trigger it everytime any element of the nested table is modified? The reason I need it is because the table needs to cache the indices of certain values, so when a value is changed, I need to re-cache the table.

Your help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to monitor assignments in nested tables, each table needs a __newindex metamethod.

Comment: I see, so there's no easier or less complicated way

Comment: how is this complicated? you have a __newindex anyway. just have it set the same __newindex to every assigned table value.  the only alternative option is to traverse over the entire table and compare its values vs some unchanged copy.

Comment: I think OP might want to declare the table like in the question instead of setting values individually.  Do do that you could add an `__index`, and when each property is accessed and have it assign the metatable with __index and __newindex to any table that is accessed if it isn't already assigned that.  That would prevent children from having their own metatables though...